# Breakpoints and changes stopped working in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a weird problem that I hope someone encountered, because I don't know if I can provide much detail about it (sorry).
I'm working with TiddlyWiki as a local HTML file. It's a wiki that is entirely in one HTML file. It has javascript plugins, also in the file. When it loads it sets them up as separate scripts in devtools[image].

I want to modify one of these on the fly. What I used to do was open the script (it opens in its own tab), edit it, save, and the changes would take effect until reload.

All of a sudden, this stopped working. Not only my changes don't take effect, but breakpoints in the script, which used to work fine no longer work. If I make the change while in a breakpoint, and save, the browser jumps to the script that calls the method in the changed script. The breakpoint no longer works and I can't step into any method in the modified script. The modifications don't take effect.

I tried using local overrides, adding, removing, resetting, deleting the files. Everything I could think of. Note that I didn't need these in the past (that is, until a few days ago).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was probably due to something with encoding. I use vi to copy&paste the text and then save as ascii, then copied that to the wiki and everything started working as expected